# Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded on Cpanel

Tags: php, file-upload, cpanel

I have a CMS on PHP(Codeigniter) in which i need to upload 25 images on weekly basis. I have increase the max_file_uploads=500 in php.ini on localhost and cpanel server. Now it is working fine on localhost but when i am trying to upload this from live server it only uploading 19 images. Please help me here as I don't know what to do as I already increase the max_file_uploads from php.ini located in public_html in Cpanel.

Comment: did you applied the changes on the live server too ? if not please apply the and tell me what you get

Comment: yes, i have update my php.ini file on live server.

Comment: now you have to change these values too .                            
 upload_max_filesize = 100M         //put here the size  what ever you want                                                                   
post_max_size = 100M //put here the size  what ever you want

Comment: tell me if it works

Comment: I have changes this thing also, but it does not affect anything, Is there any requirement to restart apache on cpanel to apply these changes as we do this on localhost xampp server?

Comment: put them in .htaccess file

Comment: Can you send me the code how to write on htacess

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Its worked. Putting this thing in .htaccess file work.

Comment: any time buddy :)